# How to add custom css animation to an element in Sencha Touch?

Tags: sencha-touch-2.1

I have a panel in Sencha Touch. Inside of the panel I have a button. Now when I click on the button, I want to increase the width of the panel with custom css animations. This is my what I have tried so far.

**Sencha Touch Code:**

```
xtype:'panel'
id:'mypanel',
style:'width:300px;-webkit-transition:width 2s;transition:width 2s;'
items:
      [
        {
            xtype:'button',
            text:'Expand',
            id:'expand'
        }
      ]
```

**Controller.js** //on button click

```
 Ext.getCmp('mypanel').addCls("expand");
```

**Custom.css**

```
.expand
{
width:600px;
}
```

Inside style of the panel, I have given some animation. But it doesnot work. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the inline style. And use 2 css classes.

**Mypanel.js**

```
 Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyPanel', {
 extend: 'Ext.Panel',

 config: {
     centered: true,
     cls: 'colapse', // Initialy added cls class
     id: 'mypanel',
     items: [
         {
             xtype: 'button',
             itemId: 'mybutton',
             text: 'MyButton'
         }
     ],
     listeners: [
         {
             fn: 'onMybuttonTap',
             event: 'tap',
             delegate: '#mybutton'
         }
     ]
  },

 onMybuttonTap: function(button, e, eOpts) {
    Ext.getCmp('mypanel').setCls('expand');  // resetting style on button tap
}

});
```

**custom.js**

```
.expand
{
width:600px;-webkit-transition:width 2s;transition:width 2s;
}

.colapse
{
width:300px;-webkit-transition:width 2s;transition:width 2s;
}
```

In the above code initially i added the cls  "colapse" to the panel and on the button tap event  i set the cls to "expand" to the panel using the following code "Ext.getCmp('mypanel').setCls('expand')".